# Conditionally setting DataGrid RowStyle highlight background and text

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpf-style

I have a DataGrid where I'm highlighting the row color/text based on a binding property QualityStatus. It works fine, but the default row highlighting disrupts the row color. I realized I could set the HighlightBrushKey as Transparent, so the color isn't changed, but this doesn't affect the "inactive" color, like if you selected a row but then focused another control. Also, I am not sure how to set the selected row font color either.

Ideally, I would just have  tags where I could just set the highlight background / text colors for each of the 3 conditions, but am unsure how to do this.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveBorderBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding QualityStatus}" Value="Poor">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>

            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding QualityStatus}" Value="Fair">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding QualityStatus}" Value="Good">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Are you using .Net 4.5 or 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

This works for .Net 4.0:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
```

And this is how you change the text color:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
```